# Machine learning's activation functions classification

Tags: functions, machine-learning

I am writing a document which compile more than 30 activation functions, and I am wondering if I can classify these functions into some main families.

*I am mostly self taught and I probably lack some academic background to really & deeply understand what I am doing, so something that might be obvious to you might not be obvious to me.*

After some time studying the various activation functions I gathered in books or online, I concluded that I could probably classify them into the following types :

- Unipolar Binary
- Bipolar Binary
- Unipolar Continuous
- Bipolar Continuous
- Linear

But some documentation I read confuse me and I am not sure any-more that I can use these terms to qualify multiple functions.

For instance, if I produce the following classification, am I right?

- **Unipolar Binary**

  - Unit Step (Step)
- **Bipolar Binary**

  - Sig (Signum / Binary Step)
- **Unipolar Continuous**

  - Sigmoid (Logistic)
  - Complementary log-log
  - ReLU
  - Smooth ReLU (Smooth Rectifier / Smooth max / Soft plus)
  - Gaussian
- **Bipolar Continuous**

  - Bipolar Sigmoid
  - Tanh
  - Hard Tanh *(--> Linear ?)
  - ArcTan
  - LeCun's Tanh
  - Softsign
  - Absolute -*(--> Linear ?)*
  - LReLU *(--> Linear ?)*
  - PReLU *(--> Linear ?)*
  - RReLU *(--> Linear ?)*
  - ELU
  - SELU
  - SReLU *(--> Linear ?)*
  - Piece-wise Linear *(--> Linear ?)*
  - Adaptative Piece-wise Linear *(--> Linear ?)*
  - Bend Indentity
  - Soft Exponential
  - Sinusoid
  - Sinc
  - Logit
  - Probit
  - Cosine
  - Softmax
  - Maxout *(--> Linear ?)*
- **Linear**

  - Identity

Beside the very probable classification errors, does this classification makes sense or am I totally wrong?

Also, as you can see in this sample, I found what seems to be similar functions under several names (e.g.: Sig / Signum / Binary Step). If this is really the same functions, why is there so many names for a given function?

Comment: Why would you need many different activations functions ? For the gradient descent we need $f$ to be differentiable, not only continuous.

Comment: So many different activation functions for so many different problems. The goal of my document is to remind me (and maybe others) that these functions exists, how they behave and what kind of problem they can solve. But my problem here is to know if I can classify these function using the 5 mentioned categories above.

Comment: Do you know the backpropagation algorithm (gradient descent applied to neural networks) ? The main point is that $\tanh(x)$ is a smoothed version of $\text{sign}(x)$.

Comment: I know what is the back-propagation algorithm and what is its purpose, but I'm still a novice in ML and obviously I lack even more mathematical background that I suspected because your comment makes literally no sense to me. Are you saying that there is no point to use different activation functions with the various ML methods (not only NN)? I could stick to the sigmoid, but I'm curious to experiment with others types of activation function to see if some functions can be more efficient than others.

Comment: There is obviously a point to use many different **objective functions**. And I didn't say there is no point to use other **smooth** (or at least continuously differentiable) activations functions, but once you have $\tanh$ $\sin$ and $\times$, do you really need many others ?

Comment: The last 10 years, the ML researchers have added the convolutional layers and the LSTM neurons in the NN toolbox. For this, instead of searching for different activation functions, they grouped $3$ or $50$ neurons to build a new "operator" with a clear meaning that the neural network can use as a black box and whose parameters are learnt during the gradient descent.